# $\sum_{l=1}^k a_l \leq \sum_{l=1}^k b_l \forall k \in \mathbb N, \sum_{l=1}^\infty b_l <\infty \Rightarrow \sum_{l=1}^\infty a_l <\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and  $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be **nonnegative** sequences in $\mathbb R$.

Suppose $$\sum_{l=1}^k a_l \leq \sum_{l=1}^k b_l \ \mathrm{\ for \ all \ } k \in \mathbb N$$
and $$\sum_{l=1}^\infty b_l <\infty.$$

Then, does $\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^\infty a_l <\infty$ hold ?

Intuitively, I think this holds
so I tried to prove by using the way with Cauchy sequence.

---

Let $A_k=\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^k a_l$ and $B_k=\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^k b_l$.

Take $\epsilon>0$.

Since $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy, there is $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t.
$$m>n>N\Rightarrow |B_m-B_n|<\epsilon.$$

Let $m>n>N,$ then $|A_m-A_n|=A_m-A_n \leqq B_m-A_n$

I want to  control $|A_m-A_n|$ by $\epsilon$.

How can I do this ? or doesn't this proposition hold ?

Comment: Hello :) Maybe it's easier. The sequences $(A_k)_k$ and $(B_k)_k$ are monotonically increasing and bounded from above by $\sup_kB_k=\sum_{l=1}^\infty b_l$. Hence, $(A_k)_k$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving the sequence is cauchy will most likely be quite difficult, and while it certainly is *possible* to prove convergence that way, in this particular example, I strongly suggest against it.

---

Instead, I suggest you prove that the series convergent "indirectly" (i.e., not with a direct application of the definition of convergence or cauchy-ness). Use the following **hint**:

Let $A_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_n$. Then, you can prove two things about the sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

1. It is increasing.
2. It is bounded above.

Since all increasing sequences that are bounded above are convergent, that should be enough.